# How to delete references to children of deleted properties

Tags: javascript, oop

When I delete an object property, I need to remove all references to descendant properties scattered around my application:

```
const people = {
    mary: {
        children: [
            john: new ChildClass(),
            paul: new ChildClass(),
            george: new ChildClass()
        ]
    },
    homer: {
        children: [
            bart: new ChildClass(),
            lisa: new ChildClass(),
            maggie: new ChildClass()
        ]
    }
};

const all_children = [];
/* pseudocode:
foreach people(children) {
    foreach children(child) {
        all_children.push(child);
    }
}
*/

all_children.forEach(child => {
    /* does something with mary and homer's children */
});

//////////////////

delete people.mary;

all_children.forEach(child => {
    /* STILL does something with mary and homer's children,
    even though mary has been deleted */
});
```

So I either need a way to delete all references to descendant properties, or I need a way to indicate that the reference is tied to a deleted parent and ignore it in my calculations.

What is the proper/most maintainable way to accomplish this.

Comment: I'm not sure there's an easy path here. Stick to a centralised source of truth, and derive everything from the centralised data, on-demand, instead of holding persisted references to it elsewhere in your code.

Comment: `delete` doesn't garbage collect if there are any lingering references about

Comment: From MDN: "The JavaScript delete operator removes a property from an object; if no more references to the same property are held, it is eventually released automatically."
In your case you will still have references through the array to the 3 ChildClass object (john, paul, george) so they won't be deleted by deleting mary. 
For a solution you can remove them from the array too, or you could recalculate the array every time you want to use it.

Comment: @spender Yeah, I need to brush up on immutability design principals. That concept has been a hangup for me for a while. Need to chuck `push()` & `delete` eventually

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really need to keep all the children in one array for performance reasons, the easier solution is to scrap the all_children array in favor of a function that returns an array of all children, like

```
function getAllChildren () {
  var all_children = [];
  /* pseudocode:
  foreach people(children) {
    foreach children(child) {
        all_children.push(child);
    }
  }
  */
  return all_children;
}
```

This way, if you delete Mary or Homer, calling this function will automatically reflect the deletion.

Comment: Ahh, i'm with you. Get the current state vs. saving a ton of references. Will have think on that. (As always, the actual project being worked on is more behemoth than the example given.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you're afraid of the children objects still exist in memory after you remove parent object from the object array. This isn't the case for javascript, because the language doesn't implement true classes. And therefore each copy of the new ChildClass() is passed by value and not reference.

Therefore you don't need to keep track of the children references in order to clean them up.

Comment: That's exactly the opposite. In javascript objects and arrays are ALWAYS passed by reference. Deleting a parent means the child is still alive and well, messing up calculations. Since there's no way to find a child's parent in Javascript (unless you set a "parent" property, for instance), any other variable that is holding that reference will have no idea its parent/ancestor no longer exists.